# How to achieve same quality between node material and a baked texture

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, baking, photorealism

I need alittle help with my textures. In the pic the 2 nice looking rocks have a material manipulated by a bunch of nodes. The 3rd rock's material was taken from a baked image. Basically I took the material from the first rocks applied it to a plane then rendered it to a 4096x4096 image that i then applied to a material. Why does the baked image have so much lower quality than the node materials and how can I get a texture from the nice looking rocks that matches them in quality?

Btw this is all in cycles render.
[image: The 2 nice looking rocks have a material manipulated by a bunch of node. The 3rd rock has a baked version.]

Comment: It might  be important how did you bake the texture because it could be affected by the scene shading while baking depending on the setup. See related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28596/how-do-i-bake-flat-textures-using-cycles (note that in current Blender versions choose *Diffuse* and uncheck 2 checkboxes).